# How to capture and put regex results to database?

Tags: php

`$d5 = preg_grep("/(@[0-9]{1,11})/", $d);`

in the code above:

`$d` is a `$_POST` method textarea input.

I have a `preg_grep` to find and capture numbers following an `@` symbol like this: `@1234567890`

I want to `INSERT` the `$d5` results to a table in the database, but since the preg_grep should return an array I can't put them in as it is. So I tried to use the following method

`$d5string = implode(", ", $d5);`

but obviously I couldn't address the `$d5` results appropriately.

How can I convert this `$d5` results to string so I can INSERT the results to a row under related column?

---

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

I wrote the below function and realized that I was giving a string to the `preg_grep` which takes an array. So my question was not logical. I'd like to update my question: How to capture and put regex results to database?

```
function activeMention($string) {
    $find = '/@([0-9]{1,11})/';
    return preg_grep($find, $string);
}
```

I replaced `preg_grep()` with `preg_match_all()` in the function. Now the error is gone and `var_dump` shows `int(0)`

on variable `$d5 = activeMention($string);` I put a `$_POST['textarea_name']` value as `$string`

**NOW:**
The function looks like this:

```
function activeMention($string) {
    $find = '/@([0-9]{1,11})/';
    return preg_match_all($find, $string, $matches);
    implode(', ', $matches);
}
```

When I try to insert the variable below to the database I get only the count of captured strings:

`$d5 = activeMention($_POST['textarea_name']);`

What I actually needed was the array values in 1 string like "@123123, @1234567, @12345"

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump($d5)`?

Comment: @syck I tried and got this error: `Warning:  preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given` which says preg_grep() don't get an array.

Comment: @syck let me update the question with more code please

Comment: You call it yourself a `$string`....

Comment: yea but error also say the `$string` is really a string. I realized it like that. : ) I'm now trying with `preg_match`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's finally how I did it:

I got rid of the function and used `preg_match_all` like this:

```
preg_match_all('/@([0-9]{1,11})/', $_POST['textarea_name'], $out);
$d5s = implode(', ', $out[0]);
```

and added `$d5s` to the `VALUES` in the query to insert into database.

Answer (score 1):

To get more than one match from a regular expression, you could use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) like this:

```
// Define string
$d = 'Here goes one @1234567890 and a @987654321';

// Run regular expression and put matches into $d5 (array with arrays)
$found = preg_match_all("/(@[0-9]{1,11})/", $d, $d5); 

// Iterate result    
foreach ($d5[0] as $number) {
    echo $number, PHP_EOL; // ... or insert into database
}
```

Output:

```
@1234567890
@987654321
```